# Setup new profile, deleted my profile, and now new user has no admin rights

Tags: user-profile, administrator

So I bought a used laptop and set up the latest version of Ubuntu on it. I initially set it up with a user profile and password for myself, but decided to give the computer away to a friend who needed it. I created her profile without a password, and then deleted my profile. She lives far away and has told me she has no admin rights, and cannot install a plug-in that she needs. We both don't know a lot about computers or Ubuntu. What instructions can I give her so that she can gain admin rights and be allowed to install software?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the command line to try to restore the admin rights.  Look at this site: 
[How can I create an administrator user from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70236/create-an-administrator-user-in-command-line)

If that doesn't work, try reinstalling ubuntu completely, I don't think a user can forcefully give themselves admin rights without the admin doing it.  You could try creating a new user with the admin rights as well, it's in the same webpage up there.