# Cannot login to Ubuntu via either GUI or virtual terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, login, login-screen

When I try to login to Ubuntu 14.04 from the GUI, it flicks back to the login screen. Also, I am not able to login via guest session.

When I try to login via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, it shows I have logged in, but then a fraction of second later it again asks me to login again.

Is there any way to log in to the system?

Answer (score 2):

Boot up your machine
press the left shift and you will see this menu

[image: recovery]

boot up in recovery mode

now with this screen 
[image: root]

select the second last option and drop to root user, test this if it works then create a new user and delete the earlier one.

To create new user : [How can I create an administrator user from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70236/how-can-i-create-an-administrator-user-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Doesnot work!!actually i installed some packages some last night.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me once when I updated my Nvidia drivers. 
If you are facing this after updating nvidia drivers , follow this,

1. Ctrl + Alt + F1
2. Remove nvidia drivers

   sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*

   sudo apt-get autoremove

   sudo nvidia-uninstall
3. Reboot