# Cannot install software - Lubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4 (installed via Ubuntu server)

Tags: server, permissions, lubuntu, software-center, raspberrypi

I have installed Lubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4 using the Ubuntu server 64 bit image, the installation went fine, everything seems to work just fine but I'm having a peculiar problem when adding users and installing software.

This is the problem, apparently only ONE user can install software, if there are more than one user on the system things break, let me explain:

After installing Lubuntu the only user is the default 'Ubuntu' account, the account can update, install software (from APT, Discover, Muon) no problem, if I create a new user (and give this account the same group memberships as the 'Ubuntu' account) the new account can login and works fine BUT, it cannot install software, it keeps getting a 'You are not authorized' error, the interesting thing is that the Ubuntu account gets the same error if is used to install software, now, deleting ANY of those accounts and leaving ONLY ONE the problem goes away.

To clarify, let's see the following scenario:

- Ubuntu is the only account (no problem, can install software)
- A new account is created (e.g. User1)
- User1 cannot install software
- Ubuntu cannot install software
- Remove User1 account
- Ubuntu can install software again
- or
- Remove Ubuntu account (leave User1)
- User1 can install software

I'm not sure where to look or how to fix this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create an administrator user from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70236/how-can-i-create-an-administrator-user-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately it doesn't matter how you create the account, the problem is the same.

Comment: It seems there's a bug in Lubuntu 20.04.